# Knowing how long a user has been registered in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to know how long a user has been created by checking User.date_joined and comparing it with datetime.datetime.now. Everything seem now to be working when I converted my datetime.datetime.now with the function then calling User.date_joined as d1 and datetime.datetime.now() as d2. I was getting unconverted data remains: .364000

```
def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Comment: `d1` and `d2` must be strings. Could you show what values are passed when you see the error?

Comment: yes they are.date_difference = days_between(str(query_user.date_joined), str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                return HttpResponse(date_difference)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert dates to strings using `str` and then back to datetimes using `strptime()`:

```
date_difference = (datetime.datetime.now() - query_user.date_joined).days
```

Also note that you don't need `abs` since joined date would be always less than now.

Comment: @Temi'Topsy'Bello I've tested it on datetime objects - it works for me. Are you getting any errors?